# Create .cat file with C#

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, cryptography, pinvoke

I'm trying to import and use CryptCATCDFEnumMembersByCDFTagEx in order to create .cat files using C#. The function is returning null and the parameters do not seem to be initialized. I wrote the corresponding code in C++ and that works fine. I'm guessing my structures are off.

Any help would be appreciated. The code should create a Good.cat file in the working directory of the program, which should contain the hashes of the files specified below [CatalogFiles].

Catalog.cdf

```
[CatalogHeader]
Name=Good.cat
ResultDir=.\
PublicVersion=0x0000001
EncodingType=0x00010001
CATATTR1=0x10010001:OSAttr:2:6.0
[CatalogFiles]
Notepad.exe=C:\Windows\Notepad.exe
```

C# sample program.

```
class Program
{
    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb427419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct CRYPTCATCDF
    {
        uint    cbStruct;
        IntPtr  hFile;
        uint    dwCurFilePos;
        uint    dwLastMemberOffset;
        bool    fEOF;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        string  pwszResultDir;
        IntPtr  hCATStore;
    }

    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct CRYPTOAPI_BLOB
    {
        public uint cbData; // UInt32 cbData;
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)]
        public IntPtr pbData; //public byte[] pbData
    } // CRYPT_INTEGER_BLOB, CRYPT_ATTR_BLOB, CRYPT_OBJID_BLOB, CRYPT_HASH_BLOB

    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SIP_INDIRECT_DATA
    {
        public CRYPT_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_VALUE Data;
        public CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER DigestAlgorithm;
        public CRYPTOAPI_BLOB Digest;
    }

    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381151%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct CRYPT_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_VALUE {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] 
        public string pszObjId;
        public CRYPTOAPI_BLOB Value;
    }

    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381133%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct CRYPT_ALGORITHM_IDENTIFIER
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pszObjId;
        public CRYPTOAPI_BLOB Parameters;
    }

    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct GUID
    {
        int     a;
        short   b;
        short   c;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        byte[]  d;
    }

    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class CRYPTCATMEMBER
    {
        public uint cbStruct;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pwszReferenceTag;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pwszFileName;
        public GUID gSubjectType;
        public uint fdwMemberFlags;
        public IntPtr pIndirectData;    //struct SIP_INDIRECT_DATA_  *pIndirectData;
        public uint dwCertVersion;
        public uint dwReserved;
        public IntPtr hReserved;
        public CRYPTOAPI_BLOB sEncodedIndirectData;
        public CRYPTOAPI_BLOB sEncodedMemberInfo;
    }

    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb410248%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void PFN_CDF_PARSE_ERROR_CALLBACK(
        [In] uint dwErrorArea,
        [In] uint dwLocalError,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszLine
    );

    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb427424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    [DllImport("wintrust.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern IntPtr CryptCATCDFOpen(
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszFilePath,
        [In, Optional] IntPtr pfnParseError
    );

    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb427423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    [DllImport("wintrust.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern string CryptCATCDFEnumMembersByCDFTagEx(
        [In] IntPtr pCDF,
        [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder pwszPrevCDFTag,
        [In] IntPtr pfnParseError,
        [In] CRYPTCATMEMBER ppMember,
        [In] bool fContinueOnError,
        [In] IntPtr pvReserved
    );

    private static void ParseErrorCallback(uint u1, uint u2, string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(u1 + " " + u2 + " " + s);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PFN_CDF_PARSE_ERROR_CALLBACK pfn = new PFN_CDF_PARSE_ERROR_CALLBACK(ParseErrorCallback);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
        string s = string.Empty;

        IntPtr cdfPtr = CryptCATCDFOpen("catalog.cdf", Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(pfn));
        CRYPTCATCDF cdf = (CRYPTCATCDF)Marshal.PtrToStructure(cdfPtr, typeof(CRYPTCATCDF));

        CRYPTCATMEMBER ccm = new CRYPTCATMEMBER();
        ccm.pIndirectData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SIP_INDIRECT_DATA)));

        do
        {
            s = CryptCATCDFEnumMembersByCDFTagEx(cdfPtr, sb, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(pfn), ccm, true, IntPtr.Zero);
            Console.WriteLine(s ?? "N/A");
        } while (s != null);
    }
}
```

Working C++ example

```
void callback(DWORD u1, DWORD u2, LPWSTR s)
{
    printf("%d %d %s", u1, u2, s);
}

typedef LPWSTR(WINAPI *CryptCATCDFEnumMembersByCDFTagEx)(
    CRYPTCATCDF                  *pCDF,
    LPWSTR                       pwszPrevCDFTag,
    PFN_CDF_PARSE_ERROR_CALLBACK pfnParseError,
    CRYPTCATMEMBER               **ppMember,
    BOOL                         fContinueOnError,
    LPVOID                       pvReserved);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CRYPTCATCDF     *cdf;
    CRYPTCATMEMBER  *pMember = NULL;
    LPWSTR          pwszMemberTag = NULL;
    HINSTANCE       dllHandle = LoadLibrary(L"wintrust.dll");

    cdf = CryptCATCDFOpen(L"catalog.cdf", (PFN_CDF_PARSE_ERROR_CALLBACK)callback);
    CryptCATCDFEnumMembersByCDFTagEx fptr = (CryptCATCDFEnumMembersByCDFTagEx)GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "CryptCATCDFEnumMembersByCDFTagEx");

    while (pwszMemberTag = (*fptr)(cdf, pwszMemberTag, NULL, &pMember, TRUE, NULL))
    {
        wprintf(L"%s", pwszMemberTag);
    }

    CryptCATCDFClose(cdf);
}
```

Comment: `public class CRYPTCATMEMBER` looks wrong. Shouldn't that be a `struct`?

Comment: @IInspectable I've tried both using class and using struct and then passing the struct as a ref param to CryptCATCDFEnumMembersByCDFTagEx after changing the signature. It compiles and runs but returns the same.

Comment: You didn't tell us where the code fails. You don't appear to have done any error checking. You've got a StringBuilder that you did not allocate memory for. Looks like you are out of your depth. I'd start by making a functioning C++ program. Then at least you'll understand the steps.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, people asking questions on SO are often out of their depth. It is failing in the function CryptCATCDFEnumMembersByCDFTagEx, whereas the C++ code return proper values (return value and parameters), the C# code does not. The reason I removed the error codes is that there is no error codes. Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); returns 0. The StringBuilder, yeah. I changed that in the last minute from a string. Still not working, though.

Comment: You check for errors by checking return values. You don't do that. Anyway, since you've got C++ and C# code you can log the values you pass as parameters and look for differences.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, my apologies but I have spent a day with the code, the return values are of course the same from CryptCATCDFOpen (for sizes, offset etc), or at least "similar" (file handle values etc) up until the call to CryptCATCDFEnumMembersByCDFTagEx. I'm unsure about the marshaling, and the definition of CRYPTCATMEMBER (and other structures), since it does not get initialized in the C# version after calling the above mentioned function. As it gets in the C++ version. The structures are also the same sizes in C++ and C#. I would really appreciate another set of eyes on the code..

Comment: @citizencane, I had the exact same problem. In my case, I was trying to create a ".cat" file for a driver package that uses the ".inf" file for installation. for this sort of driver, we can not use "MakeCert.exe". That means also we can not use  "CryptoAPI" that is supported by "MakeCert". I think I have to change my approach to use "Inf2Cat" as a signing tool.

Answer (score 1):

With minor changes to your program, I'm able to create the catalog file. Did not modify any structs or its members. Still using "CRYPTCATMEMBER" as class

Changes:

1. Assign null to string variable, in this case "s".
2. Calling CryptCATCDFClose function after enumerating the files in catalog definition file(.cdf).

Working Console program.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CRYPTCATMEMBER ccm = null;
            try
            {
                PFN_CDF_PARSE_ERROR_CALLBACK pfn = ParseErrorCallback;
                string s = null; //This null assignment is deliberately done.

                IntPtr cdfPtr = CryptCATCDFOpen("catalog.cdf", Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(pfn));
                CRYPTCATCDF cdf = (CRYPTCATCDF) Marshal.PtrToStructure(cdfPtr, typeof(CRYPTCATCDF)); //This call is required else the catlog file creation fails

                ccm = new CRYPTCATMEMBER
                {
                    pIndirectData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SIP_INDIRECT_DATA)))
                };

                do
                {
                    s = CryptCATCDFEnumMembersByCDFTagEx(cdfPtr, s, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(pfn), ccm, true, IntPtr.Zero);
                    Console.WriteLine(s ?? "N/A");
                } while (s != null);
                CryptCATCDFClose(cdfPtr); //This is required to update the .cat with the files details specified in .cdf file.
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Free the unmanaged memory.
                if (ccm != null)
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ccm.pIndirectData);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: In my case, with the exact same code, it does not enumerates files except the first one while as creates the ".cat" file in the specified path. But the size of the created ".cat" file size is zero.